# Riverpod '!_didChangeDependency': Cannot use ref functions after the dependency of a provider changed but before the provider rebuilt

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a provider that is essentially a timer that counts up in seconds only when the app is in background,

```
@riverpod
class TotalFocusTime extends _$TotalFocusTime {
  Timer? timer;

  @override
  int build() {
    //and it returns 0 when not in the background
    return 0;
  }

  void startFocusTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      // Read the current value of isBackground inside the timer callback
      bool isBackground = ref.watch(isBackgroundBoolProvider);

      // If the app is in the background, increment the state
      if (isBackground) {
        // Use ref.read to read the current state value
        state++;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this watches another provider which a boolean for when the app is in the background and I have confirmed this boolean gets updated correctly in my app.

this startFocusTimer method gets called in a button:

```
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
         
          ref.read(totalFocusTimeProvider.notifier).startFocusTimer();
         
        },
```

and it is being watched inside the countdown page where its value is being displayed in a Text widget:

```
class BuildTimer extends ConsumerWidget {
  const BuildTimer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
   (total_duration)

    int focusSeconds = ref.watch(totalFocusTimeProvider);
```

The timer counts up successfully when I comment out the isBackground check so what could be causing that error, my desired outcome is the state to count up when the app is backGround and just pause when it is in the foreground.

edit: The startFocusTimer is Getting Called from an elevated button that can be pressed only once(to start the countdown):

```
  return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ref.read(mainTimerProvider.notifier).startTimer();
          ref.read(totalFocusTimeProvider.notifier).startFocusTimer();
```

and this is where isBackground is getting updated from:

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.detached) return;

    final isBackground = state == AppLifecycleState.paused;
    final isForeground = state == AppLifecycleState.resumed;

//app either in background or the screen is locked
    if (isBackground) {
      ref.read(isBackgroundBoolProvider.notifier).setToBackGround();
      ref.read(interruptionsProvider.notifier).increment();
      print(ref.watch(isBackgroundBoolProvider));
    }
    if (isForeground) {
      ref.read(isBackgroundBoolProvider.notifier).setToForeground();
      print(ref.watch(isBackgroundBoolProvider));
```

This method is located in the countdownpage:

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `TotalFocusTime` itself, specifically where you `watch` to your `isBackgroundBoolProvider`. It cannot be `watch` or `listen` anywhere except in the `build` method. However, if you replace with `read` - it won't work.

Instead, try the following code:

```dart
@riverpod
class TotalFocusTime extends _$TotalFocusTime {
  Timer? _timer;

  late bool _isBackground;

  @override
  int build() {
    _isBackground = ref.watch(isBackgroundBoolProvider);
    return 0;
  }

  void startFocusTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      if (_isBackground) {
        state++;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Note, I have encapsulated some fields as they should not be visible from outside this class. There is also the question of whether and under what conditions the timer should be stopped - this question is left on your shoulders.

Comment: it is still not working, I have confirmed that is BackGround is getting called and successfully changed, perhaps the problem could be that I call startFocustTimer only once I will update my question to show it